# JSNI : undefiend is not a function

Tags: javascript, gwt, jsni

Im trying to implement a pickdate.js into my project :

http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date.htm

when I try to call the methode :

```
private native void exportStaticMethod(String id) /*-{

    var $input = $doc.getElementById(id)
    $wnd.pickdate()
}-*/;
```

I get

> undefiend is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `$input.pickadate()`. You should be invoking the `pickadate` function (notice that it's pick**a**date, not pickdate) on the input field, not the whole `window`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it with :

```
    txt.getElement().setId("gug");

    txt.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<String>()
    {

        @Override
        public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event)
        {
            exportStaticMethod(txt.getElement().getId());
        }

    });




        private native void exportStaticMethod(String id) /*-{

            $wnd.$('#' + id).pickadate();

        }-*/;
```